# Read latest message from kafka - segmentio/kafka-go

Tags: go, apache-kafka, segment-io

I'm using segmentio/kafka-go client to read messages from a topic.
I'm unable to find.. how to start reading from last/new message.

Everytime I start the code, it starts reading from beginning offset in that partition.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to know about consuming messages from Kafka is that each consumer client is part of a [Consumer Group](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers). Kafka stores the already processed offset for each Consumer Group at Topic-Partition level in an internal Kafka topic called `__consumer_offsets`. This enables a consumer of a Consumer Group to continue consumption from where it left off after a re-start.

In your case it means you need to set the Consumer Group (in the [KafkaConsumer API](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs) it is the configuration "group.id") and keep it constant. Only then you will be able to continue reading from the latest/new est message and not start from beginning after a re-start.